# Creating multiple text file & adding it to folder & downloading it

Tags: apex

I want to create multiple text file using apex i.e using apex i'll set the body of the text file.
Add them in a folder & zip the folder & give a link to download the folder.
Please can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My Apologies.

I have requirement to get the metadata of the reports of the selected folder.
I have a vf page that show the reports folder picklist, once the user select the folder it will show the reports of the folder & on clicking a button it will get the metadata of the report in json format.
I need to create a new text file for every report metadata, naming the file as report name, Add the file in a folder & download the folder as Zip.